# Offset Google static map center using php

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using Google maps to display a static map.

To center is on a location I use php to print the latitude and longitude.

e.g $latlng = 54.749920,-1.345552

The problem here is the static image puts that position in the center of the image (like it should)

What I want to do is move the center down slightly. To do this I need to add 200 to the first value. The 54.749920 will become 54.750120.

Is this possible to do using php? I think it had something to do with using an array to split the 2 values then adding +200 to the first, before putting them back together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have your initial `$latlng` as a string value... the example you provided would throw an error without quotes. So if you have a string, the following code will do the trick:

```
$latlng = "54.749920,-1.345552";
$coords = split(',', $latlng);
$coords[0] = strval(doubleval($coords[0]) + 0.0002);
$latlng = implode(',', $coords);
//$latlng is now "54.750120,-1.345552"
```

Please note that the code doesn't check if `$latlng` is properly formatted and might throw an error if it's not.